# Need help with conflicting regression and margins results!

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation

[image]I'm writing a thesis, for this thesis I'm doing an OLS regression with an interaction term. This interaction term turns out to be significant p < 0.05, one of the main effects is significant aswell P < 0.05, the other main effect is insignificant. However if I perform a marginsplot after my regression to visualize the interaction effect, I consistently get two parallel lines. To my knowledge this means that there is no interaction effect but an additional effect of the two main effects, is this right? If so, how can I get a significant interaction effect in my regression analysis? What do I need to do? Really hope that someone can help me.

[image]

Comment: Can you also show us that plot?

Comment: sorry for the bad language and the ugly positioning of the pictures. Any help would be welcome

Comment: Significance means that an effect size is large compared to the standard error of the estimate. Couldn't it simply be the case that you observed a small, but consistent interaction? This is what your summary suggests, at least.

Comment: With N of 67 you might be overfitting the data.